# correct command lin for launchig VMConnect

Tags: windows, shortcut, hyper-v

If I run VMConnect.exe manually and fill in the info, it works, but when I try to specify server and VM on the command line it fails (Machines hosting the VM's are all windows 8.1 machines, and clients are a mixture of Windows 7, windows 8.1, and Windows 10).

I've tried

VMConnect.exe Server "Named VM"

VMConnect.exe Server "Named VM" -G VM-UID

VMConnect.exe Server "Named VM" -G VM-UID -C 1

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found that works is:

VMConnect.exe Server "Named VM" -G VM-GUID -C 0

the "-C 0" was the answer...  either works on the command line, but I can only get it to work with "-C 0" within the application.  We have been using this solution for a couple of months now without issues.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe someone is still interested in this question after the couple of month.

In windows 10 it works this way:

1. run `cmd` as administrator
2. type `vmconnect.exe "host-name" "guest-name"`

It has to be the names you can see, if you start `vmconnect` manually. `localhost` as `hostname` is also accepted.